# Python for .NET: "TypeError: Cannot get managed object" due to getting wrong type info from .NET structs

Tags: c#, python, .net, struct, python.net

I can't make Python for .NET get the right type from my .NET struct.

Here is my C# code:

```
namespace PyNetFails
{
    public struct A
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public uint V;
    }
}
```

So the code is really simple.

Then I try to use this struct in Python:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('PyNetFails.dll')
from PyNetFails import A
a = A()
print(type(a.V))
```

and I get `<class 'int'>` although it has to be `System.UInt32`.

So when I try afterwards to run

```
from System import UInt32
v = UInt32(42)
print(v >= a.V)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    print(v >= a.V)
TypeError: Cannot get managed object
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a bug, please report in github issue tracker for pythonnet. Does UInt32(a.V) work?

Comment: @denfromufa OK, I'll report it later today. Yes, it works, thank you.

Comment: cross-ref https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/488